# How to convert swf to flv in batch

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, video, flash

i am looking for solution to convert swf into flv in a batch 
like using command line or sdk

there is solutions but the are very expansive like moyea swf video converter

can you please help me getting free/not expansive solution for converting swf into flv

thank you very much.

Comment: Did you found a solution to do this ?

Comment: hey, i got to conclusion that there is no perfect tool for it.
i check a lot a lot of products, including the "Maya" that sepose to be the best.. 

i came a cross that TotalMovieConverter of coolutils is the best.

inside the software you can create a cmd file.
so i programeticaly in a loop call for this cmd file with diffrent params everytime.

play with it... good luck.

Comment: After hours of searching, I found this app that does convert .swf to mp4 and html5 with sound and everything in sync and many other formats also in batch: `iDealshare_VideoGo_6.0.6.5638`
It doesn't seems to convert directly to flv. But you could batch convert again to flv afterwards with Handbrake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution,  i am using coolutils total converter.
insiode the program there is a way to run it as a cmd.

Answer (score 0):

There's [a perl module for this](http://search.cpan.org/dist/FLV-Info/lib/FLV/FromSWF.pm), but [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) should also be able to do so.

Comment: hi thank you for reply
using perl is to cmplex because all my project is written in php

the ffmpeg work but not good, the video output is very slow and also it does not render any actionscript...

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest converting you swf files using an SWF video converter.
I'm using this one, which can [convert swf](http://www.convertswf.com) files to more than 200 formats and it's VERY fast.